# How to change language of month date "F"?

Tags: php, date

I have this code:
`$monthNum = sprintf("%02s", $row["month"]);
$monthName = date("F", strtotime($monthNum));
echo "".$monthName. " ";`

output is `29 January 2001`
And i want to change `January` to my language Indonesian `Januari`
How i can translate/change the month name to Indonesian language?

Comment: you searched for? you tried what?

Comment: change january to januari

Comment: setlocale(LC_ALL, 'IND');

Comment: great response @RioSusanto...

Comment: @Lino ok, but sorry i duplicate...i don't know..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`date()` does not is affected by locale, you need you `strftime()`

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'IND');
echo strftime('%d %B %Y');
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for all of you guys...it's working

Comment: @RioSusanto, could you accept my answer, with green mark?

Comment: @rray how do you know `date()` not affected by locale? I am proving that, but where do you find it? is it on php documentation?

Answer (score 2):

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'IND');  // or setlocale(LC_TIME, 'id_ID');
$monthNum = sprintf("%02s", $row["month"]);
$monthName = date("F", strtotime($monthNum));
echo "".$monthName. " ";
```